# How can I use Google Apps Script to sum a column that will vary in length?

Tags: google-apps-script, formula, dynamic-data

I am trying to add a sum formula of a column at the very bottom of that column using Google Apps scipt. The number of rows will vary, but the starting cell will remain constant.

I want to use a formula instead of inserting a static sum so that users can see the up to date sum without running any scripts.

`constantslr+savingslr+needslr+wantslr` = `the number of rows to be summed`. They are defined earlier.

---

I tried this with no luck.

```
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Set Up Data');
ss.getRange(6+constantslr+savingslr+needslr+wantslr,4,1,1).setFormulaR1C1('
=SUM(-['constantslr+savingslr+needslr+wantslr']C[0]:R[-1]C[0])');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an app script formula, but if you set the region to be summed as a name range, and use:

```
 =SUM(YourRangeName)
```

it will sum the entire range.

As long as rows are inserted between the first and last row, the named range will contain all of the rows.

**Example: Rows 2 - 17 are the named range SumThing**

[image]

**Inserted 5 rows in the middle:**
The named range expands as you insert rows.  You can leave a blank row between the bottom of your data and the row containing the sum formula and then insert lines above the blank line to achieve the same thing.

[image]

**Useful in App Script also**

I use named ranges all the time within my app scripts so that I don't have to worry about somebody adding rows or columns to the sheet and breaking the script range.  To do it in app script:

```
function useNamedRange(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  // Named ranges belong to the spreadsheet, not an individual sheet
  var range = ss.getRangeByName("SumThing");

  // do something with the named range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with formula `SUM()`. But if don't feel to use ranges and want just to get the sum of all numbers above some cell here is the custom function:

```
function SUMCOL() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell  = sheet.getActiveCell()
  var col   = cell.getColumn();
  var row   = cell.getRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,col,row-1,1); // from row 1 and down to the cell with the formula
  var data  = range.getValues().flat().filter(Number); // skip empty cells and non-didgits
  var sum   = data.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
  return sum;
}
```

[image]